# Rest WS partial JSON response

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I have tried many posts found on the net before writing this question.

I'd like to have partial JSON response in my REST webservice. 
Frist, I've tried to return a JSONArray but I got

> "No converter found for return value of type: class
>   org.json.JSONArray"

Then I tried to return a list of JSONObject, I get

> "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0])"

When I set SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS to false in my application.properties, I get a list of empty JSONObjects like : {}

I share my code in GitHub with you : https://github.com/AbderrahmenISSA/StockManagement/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stockmgt/controllers/v3/ProductControllerV3.java

Comment: If by partial json response you mean just including some attributes of an entity for example, the way I found to be less painless is to have separate DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) implemented as classes with public members and no methods. If you don't know what a DTO is, google it, there is plenty material on it (in favour and against it).

Comment: I already use DTO. The problem is that is dynamic :
- one user can retrieve only one field : /products?select=productName
- another call : /products?select=productName,productCode
- another one : /products?select=productName,productCode,category.categoryName
-...
So we can't create as much DTOs as possible combinations

Answer (score 1):

in your DTO set attributes that you do not like to retrieve to null. (do it with a simple algorithm)

then configure your serilizer to not include null fields in json response. (sometimes it's the default behavior)